# Ubuntu 17.10 adding multiple static routes for NIC with Netplan

Tags: networking, 17.10, routing, netplan

I'm trying to add two static routes to my NIC. I can add one OK, but if I try to add a second, the entire network connection stops working until I bring down the 2nd card.

This is my current config which works:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: yes
    eno2:
        dhcp4: no
        dhcp6: no
        addresses: [10.10.0.11/24]
        gateway4: 10.10.0.4
        routes:
        - to: 192.168.1.0/24
          via: 10.10.0.4
```

But I need to add another route to `192.168.10.0/24` by the same gateway `10.10.0.4`

I have tried to add multiple IPs to the same route such as:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: yes
    eno2:
        dhcp4: no
        dhcp6: no
        addresses: [10.10.0.11/24]
        gateway4: 10.10.0.4
        routes:
        - to: [192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.10.0/24]
          via: 10.10.0.4
```

and

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: yes
    eno2:
        dhcp4: no
        dhcp6: no
        addresses: [10.10.0.11/24]
        gateway4: 10.10.0.4
        routes:
        - to: 192.168.1.0/24
          via: 10.10.0.4        
        - to: 192.168.10.0/24
          via: 10.10.0.4
```

But both the above causes the network to fail. How do I have to format this so that I can have two static routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out the second option IS actually correct. I just had to restart a couple of times before it started working. Strange. Use this syntax:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: yes
    eno2:
        dhcp4: no
        dhcp6: no
        addresses: [10.10.0.11/24]
        gateway4: 10.10.0.4
        routes:
        - to: 192.168.1.0/24
          via: 10.10.0.4        
        - to: 192.168.10.0/24
          via: 10.10.0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

After making changes, do the following to get it to take immediately:

```
sudo netplan apply
```